# Modelling C Programs

Tags: c, uml, modeling

I have done some research on this question and most answers are a few years old or suggest just using text.
I need to model some C code I have developed for an embedded system. It is not massively complex but there are a great number of functions and UML does not appear to cover it as this is working on the pretense that the language to be modeled is object orientated.

Whilst I have read that it isn't far fetched to modify this and still use it to try and model C I wondered what thoughts people had on this or if anyone had any suggestions for how I could professionally document or model my code?

Comment: Keep in mind, that "Unified Modeling Language (UML) is a ... modeling language in the field of **object-oriented** software engineering." While C is not object-oriented without special tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the Gtk documentation and the GTK-Doc tool:

http://www.gtk.org/documentation.html

It is a big API and it is pure C.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. While I haven't gone for your option you get the priviledge as answer as your link actually recommended the following for C;
http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/
I have just run it before doing any comments and its fantastic. It generates a full HTML page with a navigation pane (if you choose to, its fully configurable) and an interactive search box.